# Спортивное программирование

Tags: java, олимпиада

Прошу посоветовать книги по олимпиадному (**школьному**) программированию и вообще, что стоит учить, на данный момент читаю книгу Роберта Седжевика / Кевина Уэйна "Алгоритмы на Java". Предпочитаемый язык - Java.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте на странице олимпиад по информатике 179й школы: https://server.179.ru/wiki/?page=Informatika/Olimpiady

Учить стоит Java, C++
Из скриптовых Python

Процесс этот бесконечен, ибо.
Учтите что спортивное программирование даёт некий бонус при поиске работы, но опыт там очень специфический и спорный, не всегда полезный. В реальном программировании другое. Но спортивное программирование поможет вам оставаться на плаву (сохранять интерес к теме) дольше.